# Internal direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let $U,V\subset W$, then the sum $U+V$ is direct and equals $W$ if and only if $U+V=W$ and $U\cap V=\{0\}$. And in this situation say $W$ is the internal direct sum of $U$ and $V$. The definition of sum being direct is $f(u,v)=u+v:U\bigoplus V\implies U+V$ is an isomorphism.

The proof says this is true because $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if $Im(f)=W,Ker(f)=\{0\}$ why?

Here I already know the theorem $\dim_F(U+V)+\dim_F(U\cap V)=\dim_F(U)+\dim_F(V)$ but I don't think it's helpful here. But let me know if you think it is.

Also it says the definition of $U+V$ being direct is equivalent to $U\cap V=\{0\}$ why?

Edit: Okay I think I see the reversed direction. First Isomorphism Theorem tells the thing.

Comment: $f$ being an isomorphism, is both injective and surjective. The former implies $\text{Ker}(f)$ is trivial (recall definition of kernel and note that a homomorphism carries identity) and the latter implies (by definition) that $\text{Im}(f)=W$, the whole co-domain of $f$.

Comment: The backward direction I'm not very sure?